# install cordova npm hangs in loadRequestedDeps in linux OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-cordova

I am new here for asking question. If any mistake, pls forgive and correct me.
I'm trying to install Cordova on my linux ubuntu 18.04 PC.
I tried installing NodeJS and executing sudo npm install -g cordova, as suggested in Cordova docs, and it takes forever.
The output is as follows:

> npm install -g -d cordova

i hangs on the line

> loadRequestedDeps

it has stay there forever. I launched it at 10pm yesterday, and still now it is still there.

I already saw this question but the question was for windows.

The PC is an Intel i3, with 4GB RAM and a Hp probook 440g1.

Why is this happening? Is there a way I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.

1. I install latest nodejs from nodejs website: download and install .tar file to a directory where you want to install.
2. then run

> sudo npm init

3. then force npm clear cache

> sudo npm cache clean --force

4. install cordova latest

> sudo npm install -g cordova@latest